# how to remove the parenths in a where statement for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm using the intarray extension in Postgres 9.4 with Rails 4.2 and I'd like to query like this:

```
select id, tag_ids from queryables where tag_ids && {7};
```

If I do:

```
 Query.select('id, tag_ids').where("tag_ids && '{7}'")
```

I get:

```
SELECT id, tag_ids FROM "queries" WHERE (tag_ids && '{7}')
```

Can I tell Rails not to enclose this in a parenths?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard Arel-based feature, you have a limited flexibility. You can try with the [`find_by_sql`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql) method. [Here's the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html).

```
Query.find_by_sql "select id, tag_ids FROM queryables WHERE tag_ids && {7};"
```